# how do i run an ajax call after setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to jquery and even after looking at examples it eludes me. I am not using timeout: for the ajax options because the server responds fine, i just need an actual 1000ms delay to give Ruby's Resque/Redis a set amount of time to move the jobs into the queue. I just want to run the main functio() after 1000 seconds (the setTimeout at the bottom is for the 2nd half of the process, which already works great)

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "/percentcomplete",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data != null) {
                $("#status").fadeIn();
                if (data.name === "PostSaver") {
                    $(".refreshing").fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $(".rebuilding").fadeIn();
                }
                setTimeout(refreshStatus, 1000);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: im sorry, what do you need?  you have a timeout.  So, are you just trying to get it to run regardless of what kind of data is returned in the success callback?  Essentially just delaying the AJAX response?  If so, whatever you want to happen in the success method, you should just have it run in an anonymous function within the success callback.

Comment: yes I get confusion often when trying to explain things. :/ he answered it perfect below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    function ajaxFunc() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            ...
        });
    }
    setTimeout(ajaxFunc, 1000);
});
```